# VSCode - Julia Setup - Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, intellisense

I am doing this on macOS.
I am trying to get Julia set up in Visual Studio Code. When I start typing in Python or C for instance, the IntelliSense just works without hassle. I just downloaded Julia to start learning, but I can't get the IntelliSense working. Here are the steps that I have taken so far:

1. Downloaded Julia
2. Installed JuliaLang Extension for VSC
3. Set it up in the terminal and tested it by running their Mandelbrot.jl file
4. Ran the following command: `rm -f /usr/local/bin/julia sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia`
5. Opened up the settings.json and entered this in: `"julia.executablePath": "/Applications/Julia-1.6.app"`

I am wondering if my path is correct or has anything to do with the IntelliSense problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=julialang.language-julia ?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add that to my list. I will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the settings description, please set `julia.executablePath` instead of `julia.environmentPath`. The latter setting can be ignored except for fairly special circumstances.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That seemed to fix the VSC terminal. Now, I just need to figure out the IntelliSense.

Comment: I restarted my VSC, reconnected to internet, and it seems to be up and running. Thank you!

Comment: Something important that I would like to add is to make sure that VSC is in the Applications folder instead of the downloads folder!